# Mlflow model in Heroku

Tags: heroku, streamlit, mlflow

I built an MLflow model and call a prediction on a streamlit dashboard, in it work fine in local.
In Heroku, the app which works fine locally failed to send the request online, what am I missing to such deployment?

Below the error code raised.

Procfile :

```
web: mlflow sagemaker deploy -m mlflow_model/
web: sh setup.sh && streamlit run app.py
```

Heroku logs:

```
2022-01-07T10:14:15.759252+00:00 app[web.1]: Traceback (most recent call last):
2022-01-07T10:14:15.759252+00:00 app[web.1]: File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.9/site-packages/streamlit/script_runner.py", line 354, in _run_script
2022-01-07T10:14:15.759252+00:00 app[web.1]: exec(code, module.__dict__)
2022-01-07T10:14:15.759252+00:00 app[web.1]: File "/app/app.py", line 204, in <module>
2022-01-07T10:14:15.759252+00:00 app[web.1]: main()
2022-01-07T10:14:15.759252+00:00 app[web.1]: File "/app/app.py", line 119, in main
2022-01-07T10:14:15.759253+00:00 app[web.1]: pred = request_prediction(MLFLOW_URI, ml_data)[0]
2022-01-07T10:14:15.759253+00:00 app[web.1]: File "/app/app.py", line 63, in request_prediction
2022-01-07T10:14:15.759253+00:00 app[web.1]: response = requests.request(
2022-01-07T10:14:15.759253+00:00 app[web.1]: File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.9/site-packages/requests/api.py", line 61, in request
2022-01-07T10:14:15.759253+00:00 app[web.1]: return session.request(method=method, url=url, **kwargs)
2022-01-07T10:14:15.759254+00:00 app[web.1]: File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.9/site-packages/requests/sessions.py", line 529, in request
2022-01-07T10:14:15.759254+00:00 app[web.1]: resp = self.send(prep, **send_kwargs)
2022-01-07T10:14:15.759254+00:00 app[web.1]: File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.9/site-packages/requests/sessions.py", line 645, in send
2022-01-07T10:14:15.759254+00:00 app[web.1]: r = adapter.send(request, **kwargs)
2022-01-07T10:14:15.759254+00:00 app[web.1]: File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.9/site-packages/requests/adapters.py", line 519, in send
2022-01-07T10:14:15.759254+00:00 app[web.1]: raise ConnectionError(e, request=request)
2022-01-07T10:14:15.759259+00:00 app[web.1]: requests.exceptions.ConnectionError: HTTPConnectionPool(host='127.0.0.1', port=5000): Max retries exceeded with url: /invocations (Caused by NewConnectionError('<urllib3.connection.HTTPConnection object at 0x7f2452d23790>: Failed to establish a new connection: [Errno 111] Connection refused'))
```

Answer (score 0):

We have in place some [guidelines](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) to ensure we can help each other more easily:

- do not upload screenshots of code or error logs, but copy-paste and format them
- add some code and/or configuration which can help understand the context (i.e. Procfile, application startup code). It is great if you can include a Github repository (if your code is public of course) and ALWAYS avoid including passwords and tokens.

Back to your problem: can you post the Heroku logs and the code to run the streamlit app?

Comment: Hi, Thanks for your comment, will take it account.